# How to prove CSS flex is complete or identical to float？

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

For front-end developers, it seems that CSS property float is complete, we can do anything we want using float. However, how to prove flex is identical to float, also complete?

Comment: you did any code with flex or you stuck any where with flex?

Comment: just take a look at what I can quickly show you - [a comparison between table, float and flexbox in a simple layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222103/how-to-make-aside-colum-grow-with-the-size-of-the-contentent-in-parallel-column/55222588#55222588)... flex can do *much more* than float can do, you should really try it ;)

Comment: `we can do anything we want using float.` How can you center float element?

Answer (score -1):

Flex and Float are similar but not identical. For example, Flex has a lot more features such as `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to allow sections to resize depending on users view, allowing it to be more versatile.

Comment: `Flex and Float are similar but not identical` --> can you give one similarity? I don't see any